# Verify rsa signature with CryptoApi

Tags: python, c++, cryptoapi, pyopenssl

I'm trying to calculate message rsa signature in python 2 code using `rsa` or `pyopenssl` package and verify it with microsoft CryptoApi. Unfortunately, `CryptVerifySignature` is always reporting error `0x80090006: Invalid signature`.
My python code:

```
import rsa
from OpenSSL import crypto

private_key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\n0wxp8BFWEs5YAWWNw82ft5yOg81MH1n8iCIHzWTKrw==\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

message = "testmessage"
key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key)
signature = rsa.sign(message, key, 'MD5')
```

Signature becomes aa69b87840390e6032e57f4bb... bytes, and the same signature I have via `openssl dgst -md5 -sign private.pem -keyform PEM message.txt` command

My c++ code (short version):

```
const char kPublicVerifyKey[] =
  "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
  "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDFloLNqx8YZHc8D5Pk6TniJo5n\n"
  "wdvObNilEih2VZtTPCHooa/AUhz0mqh/lOKkskDNa5RCz4iTWy7wug2v+1GGlFp9\n"
  "jEtYq6foVu8N9DChvc8OIVV14PgyFCCbCJOi5ccVUh5KBCyO8FtxHiS6a8wE3glS\n"
  "wsUGfzpMdrfKCYENRwIDAQAB\n"
  "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

...

  std::vector<unsigned char> key_buffer(public_key.size);
  DWORD key_buffer_size = key_buffer.size();
  if (!CryptStringToBinaryA(static_cast<const char*>(public_key.data),
    public_key.size, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64HEADER,
    key_buffer.data(), &key_buffer_size, NULL, NULL))
  {
    return false;
  }

  CERT_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO* key_info = nullptr;
  DWORD key_info_size = 0;
  if (!CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO,
    key_buffer.data(), key_buffer_size,
    CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &key_info, &key_info_size))
  {
    return false;
  }

  HCRYPTPROV crypt_context;
  if (!CryptAcquireContext(&crypt_context, NULL, NULL,
    PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
  {
    return false;
  }

  HCRYPTKEY crypt_key;
  if (!::CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(crypt_context,
    X509_ASN_ENCODING, key_info, &crypt_key))
  {
    return false;
  }

  HCRYPTHASH hash;
  if (!::CryptCreateHash(crypt_context, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hash)) {
    return false;
  }

  if (!::CryptHashData(hash,
    static_cast<const BYTE*>(message.data), message.size, 0))
  {
    return false;
  }

  BOOL result = ::CryptVerifySignature(hash,
    static_cast<const BYTE*>(signature.data), signature.size,
    crypt_key, NULL, 0);
```

Why `CryptVerifySignature` think that my signature is incorrect? A found related questions ([php openssl signed string not getting verified by Win CryptoAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775792/php-openssl-signed-string-not-getting-verified-by-win-cryptoapi)) with advice to reverse just signature or signature and public key data bytes, but doing this with signature changes nothing and reversing public key results in error `ASN1 bad tag value met. 0x8009310b` by `CryptDecodeObjectEx` function.

Private key was generated with `openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024` command and public was generated with `openssl rsa -in private.pem -inform PEM -outform PEM -pubout`

Comment: *Never* use that private key for anything *ever* again, now that you've published it on the internet.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I have posted it here only to let anyone reproduce the same behaviour with same data. This key was generated just for this post.

Comment: That's fine. All I'm saying is that now that you have done so, that key should *never* be used again for *anything*.

Comment: @xpp_T - I believe you need to reverse the bytes in the representation of the key. CryptoAPI uses little endian, while OpenSSL uses big endian. Its kind of a well known problem once you learn about it. There's a few Q&A on Stack Overflow on the subject. Also see [Google: openssl cryptoapi reverse bytes](http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+cryptoapi+reverse+bytes).

Comment: @jww - I have tried this by adding `key_buffer.resize(key_buffer_size);
  std::reverse(key_buffer.begin(), key_buffer.end());` before CryptDecodeObjectEx call, but it started to return `ASN1 bad tag value met. 0x8009310b` error. Anyway, I will think in that direction, thanks

Comment: @xpp_T - I believe you need to do it for each big integer, and not the whole key data structure.